# Symfony2 : Custom authentication

Tags: authentication, symfony, single-sign-on

I'm trying to make a custom authentication using Symfony2. The users are already authenticated thanks to a cookie, let's call it BASECOOKIE, on a specific domain, let's say basedomain.com

There's an application on basedomain.com that can handle authentication request and return true or false, checking wheter the user has a valid BASECOOKIE or not.

In order to do that, my Symfony2 application (which is located on another domain) needs to send that request using some auto-post form (so that the request is sent from the user and not from the app).

Do you have any idea of how I could implement that kind of authentication mecanism ? Cause I easily make basic database authentications, but when it comes to a specific one like this, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I actually implemented something similar with custom authentication and user providers:

- [How to create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)
- [How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)